# Expose header used in static framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-linking

I have a static framework B which I use inside a framework A. B has a class C I want to also expose in A, i.e. in the illustration below I want the App to be able to use the class.

App > framework A > static framework B > class C

If I try to include the header for C in the public headers of A, I get 'duplicate interface definition'. But as the code is compiled into A from B, I just need to expose the class interface – presumably that will allow the App to link correctly...?

Comment: Create a header to import B and C, then import it in A?

Comment: I can import the header fine, it's making it public in A that is causing me issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this through a bit of a workaround.

When a static library/framework is compiled into another framework/static library, its symbols are still exposed (verify through `nm <binary> | grep <symbol>`). This means you just need your App code to know about those symbols – i.e. including the header for class C in framework A.

In your headers in framework A, you need to include the class C header. When compiling the framework you need to use `"ClassC.h"`, but when the framework is being used you need `<FrameworkName/ClassC.h>`, as that is its location in the framework included by the App. To do this you use a macro which is removed in a run script phase.

So, in your framework A target build phases, make sure your header for Class C is in the 'public' section of your copy headers phase, then add a 'Run Script' phase and paste the following:

```
TARGET_MACRO="TARGET_FRAMEWORK"
cd -P "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$WRAPPER_NAME/Headers/"
perl -0pi -e "s/\#if ${TARGET_MACRO}.*?\#else\r?\n?(.*?)\r?\n?\#endif/\1/sg" *.h
```

Change `TARGET_FRAMEWORK" to be whatever, or leave it.

In Framework A build settings, under preprocessor macros, add `TARGET_FRAMEWORK=1` for all build configurations.

Then, in your Framework A headers that include Class C, use:

```
#if TARGET_FRAMEWORK
#import "ClassC.h"
#else
#import <FrameworkA/ClassC.h>
#endif
```